# Avoiding duplicate options in PHP form

Tags: php, forms, html-select

When I submit the form, it saves `InputField1` in my database, but the last saved selected `option` is shown twice in the list.

```
<select name="<?php echo $PLUGINMATRIX_NAME?>InputField1" id="<?php echo $PLUGINMATRIX_NAME?>InputField1">
<option value="<?php echo get_option($PLUGINMATRIX_NAME."InputField1");?>"><?php echo get_option($PLUGINMATRIX_NAME."InputField1");?></option>
<option value="xvg">Verge</option>
<option value="xrp">Ripple</option>
</select>
```

How do I avoid showing duplicates in the above `select` after submitting the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
<select name="<?php echo $PLUGINMATRIX_NAME?>InputField1" id="<?php echo $PLUGINMATRIX_NAME?>InputField1">
    <option <?php echo (get_option($PLUGINMATRIX_NAME."InputField1") == 'Verge') ? "selected " : "";?> value="xvg">Verge</option>
    <option <?php echo (get_option($PLUGINMATRIX_NAME."InputField1") == 'Ripple') ? "selected " : "";?> value="xrp">Ripple</option>
</select>
```